# find columns in Dataframe where every row has a value

Tags: python, pandas

how can I find the columns which have a value in every row
My pd.DataFrame looks like this:

```
     A    B    C    D
1    1    2    3    2
2    2    2         1
3         3    2    1
```

i would like to get this output

```
     B    D
1    2    2
2    2    1
3    3    1
```

how can i detect the right columns?

Thank you,
R

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of a question asking for columns containing any null value. You just need to use the negative of this, i.e. the `~` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use if no values are missing values:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.notna().all()]
#oldier pandas versions
#df1 = df.loc[:, df.notnull().all()]

print (df1)
   B  D
1  2  2
2  2  1
3  3  1
```

**Explanation**:

Compare no missing values by by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
print (df.notna())
       A     B      C     D
1   True  True   True  True
2   True  True  False  True
3  False  True   True  True
```

Check if all values in columns are `True` by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df.notna().all())
A    False
B     True
C    False
D     True
dtype: bool
```

---

If no values are empty strings compare by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) `(!=)`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.ne('').all()]
```